# Enable 3rd-party keyboard and disable Gboard programatically

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard, gboard

I'm currently facing a penetration test item in Android to create a 3rd-party keyboard and disable the usage of the default Google Keyboard, Gboard on the application. However, as much as we tried, the tester is able to make the Gboard appear over our 3rd-party keyboard.

Is there a way in Java to disable Gboard from my Java code?

Comment: Hopefully that is not possible. The choice of keyboard is up to the user.